# XStreamingElement as part of an XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to write a very large XML document, so [`System.Xml.Linq.XStreamingDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xstreamingelement(v=vs.110).aspx) seemed like the ideal solution.

I thought I would be able to construct the `XDocument` to contain the `XStreamingDocument` and only when I call `Save()` would the tree be traversed and the enumerable be iterated.

```
public void WriteXml(IEnumerable<string> lotsOfStrings, TextWriter output)
{
    var rootElement = new XElement("Root", 
       new XStreamingElement ("Strings", lotsOfStrings.Select(s => new XElement("Line", s))));

    var document = new XDocument(rootElement);
    document.Save(output);
}
```

But this isn't the case. As soon as I add an `XStreamingElement` to a containing element, it iterates the enumerable and generates all of the elements.

I intend this long element list to be nested several elements deep. Do I have to write the containing structure manually using an `XmlWriter` before calling `XStreamingElement.WriteTo()`? This would be a bit tedious and end up with me mixing paradigms (`XmlWriter` and `System.Xml.Linq`). It would seem to really limit the usefulness of `XStreamingElement`.

Or am I missing some way of constructing a document that contains streamable elements?

Comment: How do you know it iterates through the elements, when you add it to XDocument? If you've displayed its value while debugging, then that would've caused `.ToString()` to be called and forthwith the iteration of elements.

Comment: @xjuice I put a breakpoint within the `Select` lambda. That got hit before `document.Save()` was hit. Can also be verified using an iterator that has a side-effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything you wrap inside a non-streaming element (i.a. `XElement` and `XDocument`) is iterated and generated right away. If you change your *Root* element type from `XElement` to `XStreamingElement`, then the linq query is not executed right away. You may use `XElement` for leaf-nodes that are generated lazily with linq (like your *Line* element), but you will have to use `XStreamingElement` for any element which has dynamic content you don't want to be generated prematurely.

You can build even bigger structures with separately defined nested `XStreamingElement`'s. I've demonstrated this in my code example by introducing the *Strings* element separately. You could also use your own *[Iterators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx)* instead of linq queries to create dynamic content.

Last but not least, `XStreamingElement` has method `Save(TextWriter writer)`, so you don't actually need `XDocument` either.

```
public static void WriteXml(IEnumerable<string> lotsOfStrings, TextWriter output)
{
    var stringsElement = new XStreamingElement("Strings",
        lotsOfStrings.Select(s => new XElement("Line", s)));
    var rootElement = new XStreamingElement("Root", stringsElement);

    //No XML is generated yet

    rootElement.Save(output); //Whole XML is generated and saved to output
}
```

Comment: Bang on. I had thought that I would need to wrap it in an `XDocument` in order to output the XML directive etc, but there's no need. Thanks.